# What does it mean when Java could not read the lastModifiedTime attribute on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, wildfly, nio, filesystemexception

A customer has lots of following stacktraces appearing in the logs of my application.
It runs on WildFly 18 and JDK 11 on Windows Server.

```
2022-10-14 14:36:19,382 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-2) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /application/images/gray/qtip/nul}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\PROGRAM\SAUSAGE\wildfly-gui\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp5bd4c0db725d6b53\content-d8575e88ce594507\images\gray\qtip\nul: The parameter is incorrect.

    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResource.getLastModified(PathResource.java:65)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletResource.getLastModified(ServletResource.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.CachedResource.<init>(CachedResource.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.CachingResourceManager.getResource(CachingResourceManager.java:119)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.CachingResourceManager.getResource(CachingResourceManager.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatches.java:96)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:91)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$OptionsHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:399)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$AcmeResourceHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:421)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$HostRootHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:430)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.NameVirtualHostHandler.handleRequest(NameVirtualHostHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.error.SimpleErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SimpleErrorPageHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.CanonicalPathHandler.handleRequest(CanonicalPathHandler.java:49)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Server$DefaultHostHandler.handleRequest(Server.java:190)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.ChannelUpgradeHandler.handleRequest(ChannelUpgradeHandler.java:211)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisallowedMethodsHandler.handleRequest(DisallowedMethodsHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:255)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:59)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.3.Final//org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.3.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1176)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.3.Final//org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.3.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\PROGRAM\SAUSAGE\wildfly-gui\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp5bd4c0db725d6b53\content-d8575e88ce594507\images\gray\qtip\nul: The parameter is incorrect.

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.getLastModifiedTime(Files.java:2315)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResource.getLastModified(PathResource.java:63)
    ... 36 more
```

So always the method **getLastModifiedTime** triggers this issue. Does this mean that there are issues with permissions problems? I guess that my Java program doesn't have the sufficient rights to access these files, but I'm not sure about this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share the code that calls `.getLastModifiedTime()`? Where does the colon (`:`) in `\nul:` come from?

Comment: @Ivar - I guess it's part of the message, not the filename.

Comment: @accessviolation I don't think so. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208566/typically-what-does-it-mean-when-java-returns-a-the-parameter-is-incorrect) mentions the same error message (where the path doesn't end in a colon) and the answer mentions it is often caused by a colon in the path (the colon for the driver-letter excluded).

Comment: After searching for [`images\gray\qtip`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22images/gray/qtip%22), it looks like something to do with a GXT theme. You somehow ended up with an file called `nul:` in there. Across all those google results, no one else's directory contained anything like that. It should contain 3 or 4 gifs, and that's it

Comment: I don’t think the colon is part of the filename, only part of the exception message. The problem is that the file’s base name is `nul` which is not allowed in Windows.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file.

Comment: The name 'nul' refers to the null device,  regardless of the directory path precediing it (DOS-compatible misfeature). You can't **create** a file named nul. but you can open for reading a file named nul. The trouble is, it's a device file, and does not have a 'last modified time'.  @VGR, you should perhaps write this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the underlying exception:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\PROGRAM\SAUSAGE\wildfly-gui\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp5bd4c0db725d6b53\content-d8575e88ce594507\images\gray\qtip\nul: The parameter is incorrect.
```

We can see that the file’s final path component is `nul`.  That name is not allowed in Windows at all, which is the reason for the cryptic exception message (which probably came from Windows, not from Java).  This is documented at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file%E2%80%8A) :

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM0, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT0, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended.

Solution:  don’t name a file `nul`.